# how to make Apache proxy http requests to https

Tags: apache, svn, ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure svn mirroring with transparent proxying as described [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy), but getting hard times with https.
Current setup is:

- master server is available publicly and is protected by https.
- slave server is sitting behind a nginx reverse proxy, and serves via http, but nginx is protecting all the external traffic with https.

so I managed to setup svnsync to work over this weird setup, but struggling with writethruproxy:
mod_proxy_http does not like https on the other end and says this:

```
[debug] proxy_util.c(1525): [client ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc] proxy: *: found reverse proxy worker for https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/svn/my_repo/!svn/me
[debug] mod_proxy.c(1020): Running scheme https handler (attempt 0)
[debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1954): proxy: HTTPS: declining URL https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/svn/my_repo/!svn/me (mod_ssl not configured?)
[debug] mod_proxy_ajp.c(677): proxy: AJP: declining URL https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/svn/my_repo/!svn/me
[debug] mod_proxy_ftp.c(842): proxy: FTP: declining URL https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/svn/my_repo/!svn/me - not ftp:
[debug] mod_proxy_connect.c(100): proxy: CONNECT: declining URL https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/svn/my_repo/!svn/me
[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /svn/brisbane/!svn/me. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

TLDR: is there any way I could configure mod_ssl and mod_proxy_http to forward http traffic to https?

- TIA

Comment: please elaborate on the TLDR comment

Comment: the trick was to add 

    SSLProxyEngine on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll first need to enable mod_ssl (e.g. `a2enmod ssl` on a Debian/Ubuntu box, or alter the configuration to load the module as required on your installation).

Then, you'll need to configure the `SSLProxy*` directives as indicated in the [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) documentation, more specifically, at least `SSLProxyCACertificateFile` or `SSLProxyCACertificatePath` with which CA you're willing to trust (since your Apache Httpd server will be a client in that respect).

Comment: thanx, that helped! adding certificates wasn't necessary, though. The only thing that I did was to enable mod_ssl and add SSLProxyEngine on **above** my svn sections.

Comment: @user1308092, the default `SSLProxyVerify none` option makes the connection between the proxy and the actual server vulnerable to MITM attacks, since it doesn't verify anything. You should generally set it to `required`, and follow the note in the [red box in its documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyverify).